# xamp not able to install on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, xampp

I am having errors while Installing Xamp 32 bit packages on 64 bit windows 8.1

(I could not get 64 bit downloads for windows 8 from Xampp page https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.2.9/)

I installed Xampp in G:\software installations\xamp

visual c++ 2008 redistributable complaint:

[image]

apache port 443 error:

[image]

what is solution for these errors? how to fix them?

Microsoft visual C++ all redistributable are properly there in the system.
You can see this snapshot.

microsoft all re distributables present:

[image]

There was one more error the UAC error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTfOh.jpg)

Comment: Please provide the installation log.  This is required to properly diagnose the installation error you received, it's not unclear if you resolved that error, since you actually have the XAMPP control panel installed

Comment: where are these installation logs I checked my installation folder "G:\software installations\xampp\"  I could not find

Comment: In order to run Apache on port 443, you would have to change the port your VMWare installation is running on, or change the port Apache uses.  I am going to assume you eventually solved the Visual C++ error since you got XAMPP Control Panel working..

Comment: no I could not solve Visual C++ error I uninstalled xampp and reinstalled xampp the same error as posted in screenshot 1 is there.

Comment: 7.2.9 requires VC15, which is Visual C++ 2017, not Visual C++ 2008.  I figured that out by looking at what VC++ Apache and PHP requires

Comment: I installed 64 bit Visual C++ 2017 but the error is same it asks for Visual C++ 2008 package.

Comment: I uninstalled every thing and installed every thing this time ran installer as admin and there was no VC++ redistributable error I have added a last screenshot which was also happening during each installation and it happened in the last installation which went smooth even though  I ran as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Below are possible solutions to the two problems.

**Port 443 in use problem**

See the post
[How to stop VMware port error of 443 on XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182512/how-to-stop-vmware-port-error-of-443-on-xampp-control-panel-v3-2-1)
for several solutions.

The easiest solution would be to :

- In VMware Workstation Server open the menu *Edit > Preferences*
- Click Shared VMs
- Click Disable Sharing
- Change port
- Click Enable Sharing

[image]

**Visual C++ 2008 redistributable missing**

I have no explanation for that.
You may find a newer XAMPP version 7.2.10 / PHP 7.2.10 in the site
[Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html#),
which might work better.

Ensure first that the existing version is uninstalled and the target folder
is empty (if not then delete all files in it).

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions above I was able to resolve vmware port error which was conflicting with Xampp setup but the Visual C++ redistributable error was not going even though I installed VC ++ 2017 as per suggestion above lastly uninstalled and re installed with run as administrator , how ever an error did came this time 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9awKC.jpg)

But after wards installation went smooth and this was most clean install with this single warning/alert. 
I am still open to suggestions /answers.

Comment: That warning isn't an error.