# is xampp available for 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, xampp

I want to install xampp I looked at website
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html#

but I could not find 64 bit version for windows 8 does that mean there are no 64 bit xampp downloads for windows 8.

I want to install 64 bit because I downloaded 32 bit xampp and then it gave me a lot of errors which you can see here 
[xamp not able to install on windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/1364933/xamp-not-able-to-install-on-windows-8/1364944#1364944)

so please let me know where can I find 64 bit xampp for windows 8.1

Comment: The only Windows installer is the first download on the page you linked to.  Any event, the error you received, can be solved by installing the 32-bit version of Visual C++ 2008

Comment: see this image all the redistributable are present in the system https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2NVm.jpg

Comment: I will address the solution to your other question, in an answer, to your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not find a 64-bit version for Windows 8, does that mean there isn't a 64-bit XAMPP download, that supports Windows 8?

XAMPP does not include the 64-bit versions of [Apache](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/) and [PHP](https://windows.php.net/download/).  This means that a 64-bit XAMPP installation cannot exist.  While XAMPP includes more than Apache and PHP, it primarily exists, in order to make the system configuration of those two software packages easier.

*It is worth pointing out that, if you are willing to configure Apache and PHP by hand the use of XAMPP is not required.*  As for the port error you received, that can be resolved, by configuring XAMPP and Apache to run on a different port.

> So please let me know where can I find 64-bit XAMPP for Windows 8.1

It does not exist

Comment: Worth pointing out that at least one of those downloads is meant to be used with VC15, which means Visual C++ 2017 is required, which you don't have installed.